# Android Studio path

Tags: java, android, streamwriter

Hey Guys I did a little App, where  I type into a textbox a specific value (height, weight) and save it into a file. 
I did this but I do not know, which path I have to use for Android.

Hope you can help :)

```
 public void SaveList(View view) {
        //Pf`enter code here`ad, im privaten Speicherbereich
        File file = new File("I need this path :)");
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter fdg = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
            fdg.write(""+this.weight);
            fdg.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Environment.getDataDirectory()` to get the root directory, if you dont have an SD card.

If you have an SD card, use `Environment.getExternalStorageState()`

Read more about them in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

Thus, change your code as follows

```
File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/your_folder_name/your_file_name");
```

This will create a file with name `your_file_name` in the folder `your_folder_name` in your internal storage.

Comment: Great...did that help you?